# Adding keys to Secure Boot database on an HP Pavilion 14-ab057ca

Tags: uefi, certificate, hp-pavilion, secure-boot

I am trying to add a custom key in the Secure Boot database.
Don't tell me "Activate Setup Mode", " Change the PK", "Add a KEK" or anything, I know how to do it.
The problem is: I can't switch my machine to setup mode.

In the below picture, I am in the UEFI Configuration Utility, and trying to access the advanced settings for it, but they are grayed out. According to what Microsoft asked to mark a computer as "Windows 8 Ready", the customer is able to edit the secure boot keys. So why are they grayed out? How can I activate those? Could anything in my configuration disable these options?

[image: UEFI Configuration Utility]

PS: "touche plateforme" means Platform Key (it looks like Google Translate passed by...)

Comment: HP consumer notebooks do not allow you to do this, Business notebooks do.

Comment: @Moab But why does the Windows Harware Certification says that we need to be able to add keys for it to be certified "Windows 8 Ready", but my computer wouldn't allow it?

Comment: On Business laptops you use ctrl+A while in the bios to access advanced menus, but on consumer notebooks all you will get is a beep when you do it, but give it a try anyway.

Comment: If you have no luck contact HP about your issue.

Comment: Ctrl + A didn't worked (I would have expected it). HP Forums about this topic only contains people who complains. I'll try my luck with the HP Support...

Comment: HP consumer bios's have always sucked (very limited), always better to buy one of their business laptops. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll keep this topic updated depending of the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP's support sent me back to Microsoft, and Microsoft just ditched me:

[image]

I think I'm going to stay with `shim`

Answer (score -1):

According to https://github.com/Foxboron/sbctl/issues/171: try "removing/clearing the PK to put it in setup mode" in the UEFI setting interface.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160886)

Comment: -1 This answer is useless; the question was about the option to clear the PK key in UEFI settings being grayed out.